# Laravel Session Cookie gets set to HttpOnly after first API Request

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to connect an angular application to my Laravel backend. Login works as intended, however the session cookie gets set to HttpOnly after the first API Request, even though I set the option

```
'http_only' => false
```

In the session.php config file.

[Set-Cookie Response after calling /login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA4z0.png)

[Set-Cookie Response after calling /config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hea5m.png)

I'm aware of the fact, that exp seems to be in the past, however when I open the cookie overview via the button next to the url, it displays it correctly expiring in two hours.

I tried removing

```
\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class
```

from the API middleware group, that did not help. Other settings that I tinkered with are:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SESSION_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000,localhost:4200
```

I'm using Laravel version 8.4 and Sanctum version 2.11. What am I missing?

Comment: Why would you need client-side access to the _session_ cookie in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe I'm using it in my Auth Guard. If that cookie is not present, I route the user to /login.

Comment: I think this [post](https://pineco.de/accessing-front-end-cookies-laravel/) will help you.

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin thank you for sharing that link. The post talks about cookie encryption for cookies created in frontend. I'm trying to access a cookie in my frontend, that has been created in my backend. Also, cookie encryption is set to false in my session config.

Comment: @lum_dev were you able to solve this? Mind sharing your solution?

Comment: @DavidLartey No sorry I actually do not remember how I solved this. I think it was an issue with having a lot of conflicting settings regarding sessions etc. If you're struggeling regarding this, try comparing your settings with the out of the box config as provided with a fresh laravel install and give it a go. Is your issue exactly the same? I can share my config if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks. Weirdly, I left the server for a while (I think I restarted it too) and my subsequent requests started working just fine. ‍♂️